# Reach NAT VMs from all Clients

Tags: networking, router, virtual-machine

So this is my desired situation is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI1Cd.png).

My Router (FRITZ!Box) is connecting everything to the internet. `SVR-DATA` is running Windows Server. On that server I want to run Virtual Machines which are reachable from all computers in the local network.

Because Bridging does not work on my computer (for some reason, I gave up on that) and for trying to learn how subnets work, I wanted to setup a subnet where all VMs are connected. The server is running VMware Workstation with Shared VMs and I got it so far as the VMs are able to connect to the internet and the rest of the network (using the 192.168.208.X, which isn't difficult). No problem so far.

But I can't reach the VM from my normal computer which is running in the "normal" subnet (192.168.1.X). When I `tracert` to my VM (`tracert 192.168.208.10`) I reach my Router (192.168.1.1) which has a static route configured to my server's subnet and then it times out. I've installed and configured Windows Server to do routing but maybe my routing config is all wrong but at this point I don't know to help myself anymore.

I'd love to get some help on that topic because I don't really know how to continue. If you can help me with this problem I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Traceroute tests are failing at the router (192.168.1.1) it is safe to assume that you may have an incorrect route.

You will need a static route on you router (192.168.1.1) to point to the 192.168.208.0/24 network with a next hop of 192.168.1.250.

Verify 192.168.1.250 will route 192.168.208.0/24.  Disable any software firewalls on 192.168.1.250 during testing.  Make sure that 192.168.1.250 will respond to ICMP or it may not give an accurate Traceroute results.

192.168.1.1 is the gateway for all of the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.   If it does not have a correct route for 192.168.208.0/24, it will route the traffic using its default route and the traffic will egress out its WAN interface to the internet.   ISPs drop all RFC1918 destined traffic, thus it is dropped.

Comment: I just rechecked the settings on my Router (192.168.1.1) and found the problem. You get 3 fields: IPv4 network: 192.168.208.1, Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0, Gateway: 192.168.1.250. I changed the IPv4 network to 192.168.208.0 and now the tracert works!

Comment: Yep, that make sense as 192.168.208.1 is the interface address and 192.168.208.0 is the network address.